# Rename class in external dll without losing reference to it in unityEditor

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

We've got a visualstudio solution with all our code in it and it's completely seperated from our unity project.
When we build our code into a dll from within visualstudio, the dll is copied over to the unity project plugins folder, so we can use the classes from it in our unity project.

This all works fine, but the problem is when we rename a class in our visual studio solution, rebuild the dll and go back to the unity project, the reference to the renamed class is lost in our scene and/or prefabs...

I looked into the scene & prefab files and noticed the references to the classes in the dll are defined as follows:

m_Script: {fileID: 698634159, guid: aa20b9c3579870b40bb96d13672546a3, type: 3}

I read on the forums that the fileID is generated based on the namespace & name of the class file, so logically when the class is renamed, this fileID changes and unity does not know it needs to reference the renamed class.

Is there a way to define a hard references of some kind, so the reference does not get lost when renaming a class? Or any other suggestions to keep references from getting lost.

I've also tried including a meta file with a guid in the dll, but unity does not seem to take this meta file into account, as it always uses the guid of the dll together with the generated fileId.

Answer (score 1):

Unity can't automagickaly find out you have renamed some class inside the DLL. That's true for any form of project : if you depend on some DLL, and classes changes in the DLL, there is no indication of rename.

The best way to link them is adding your Unity project in the solution, and place a dependance between Unity project and the another. Then maybe the refactor tool will suggest you the rename in the Unity project.

Comment: Well, i'm not really asking unity to automagically find out, i would like to find a way to make a hard reference from unity to my class, so the dependency isn't lost when i rename or move my class. Something like an annotation with a guid on the class would be quite handy, but unity seems to link with a fileid that is generated based on the name & namespace

Comment: Don't think there is much hard link possible with classes. Note that it exists for script values : [FormerlySerializedAs("myValue")]. But that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is that you can't really use a refactor tool to rename the references on the prefabs/scene

Comment: With a manual table oldName -> newName, you may be able to use an editorScript to change everything.

Comment: The problem with that is that unity does not use names, but fileid's, so there is still an old file id in scenefile, but you have to know which fileid was the old one and then replace it with the new fileid. The only way you can find out these fileids is to add them to an empty scene and look in the scene file for the id... This is quite a cumbersome task to do after a refactor where multiple classes have been renamed..

Comment: It's a reasonable feature request. Actually it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good tool to find and replace missing scripts, which i assume is the error you are getting.

http://daikonforge.com/forums/resources/fix-missing-scripts.3/

It comes with the source code once you unpack the Unity3d Package, so you can customize it to your needs.